# How to set output as a list without space?

Tags: python, list

`n` is an integer and `xs` is a list of integers.

```
n = 2
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def multiples(n,xs):
    empty = []
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] % n == 0:
            print(xs[i])
        return empty
```

It should give me the output of 2, 4, 6 in three separate lines. Is any way I can merge them into a list that without space and only commas?

```
n=3 
xs=[11, 13]
```

Will the output become '[]', the empty set?

Comment: Why do you bother using `range()` when you only ever use the elements themselves?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I agree.  Take a look at my answer.

Comment: just use append() method of list . In provided case it will be empty.append(xs[i])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code. The first problem is that you are only checking the first element in your array, and then you are returning out of your function. So, you are never actually completing iterating over your entire list.

Second, you are simply printing your items out, and per your requirements, and based on the fact that you created a list called `empty`, you want to collect this data and output it when you are finished.

With that being said, what you want to do instead is change your print statement to append to your list:

```
empty.append(xs[i])
```

Then when you are finished your for loop return empty.

Like this:

```
def multiples(n,xs):
    empty = []
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] % n == 0:
            empty.append(xs[i])
    return empty
```

Comment: If he is returning `empty`, he presumable knows that it is empty, and intends it to be so.  Don't ask me why, but that's what I would assume.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change your `for` loop to this:

```
print(",".join(str(x) for x in xs if not x % n))
```

A generator expression that does it all.  I am assuming that your `return empty` line is just indented incorrectly because at that indentation, it would print only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
n = 2
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(xs, 1) if not i % n]
[2, 4, 6]

xs = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(xs, 1) if not i % n]
[3, 5, 7]

n = 3
xs = [11, 13]

>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(xs, 1) if not i % n]
[]
```

This results in a list of integers instead of strings.

As you want to take every n'th item from your list, you need to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) (starting with a value of 1).  The `if xs[i] %n == 0` solution just happened to work because the list a continuous range.  Try `xs = [3, 3, 3, 3]` and see what happens with your function and the other solutions...

To help understand what is going on, here is a table of the interim values.

```
   i  x  i % 2 not i % 2
  == ==  ===== =========
   1  3      1     False
   2  3      0      True
   3  3      1     False
   4  3      0      True
```